# Evaluate the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}n.\mu(X_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let , $(X,M,\mu)$ be a positive measure space and let $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Let , $X_n=\{x\in X :|f(x)|>n\}$. Then show that , $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}n\mu(X_n)=0$.

AS, $f\in L^1(\mu)$ so , $f$ is real valued almost everywhere. When $n\to \infty$ then $\displaystyle \mu(X_n)=\mu\left(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>\infty\}\right)=0.$So the given limit is $0$.

Is it correct or something wrong ?

If something wrong then please provide some hints how to prove it.

Comment: Forgetting all that measure-theoretic language, you are arguing that $a_n \to 0$ implies $n a_n \to 0$. Does it seem valid?

Comment: If $\mu$ was the Lebesgue measure, $X=\mathbb R$, then $f(x)=i e^{-x^2} \in L^1(\mu)$ which is real-valued nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Use the dominated convergence theorem to prove this. Define a sequence of functions by 
$$g_n(x):=\chi_{X_n}(x)|f(x)|.$$
Because $f\in L^1(\mu)$ also $g_n\in L^1(\mu)$ for all $n$ and $|g_n|\le |f|$. The sequence $(g_n)$ converges pointwise (for fixed $x$ choose $n>|f(x)|$) to the zero function. So we get
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X_n}|f|d\mu=\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty } \int_X g_nd\mu=\int_X \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  g_nd\mu=0.$$
Then by the definition of $X_n$
$$n\mu(X_n)=n\int_{X_n} d\mu=\int_{X_n} n d\mu\leq   \int_{X_n} |f| d\mu \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty.$$

Comment: I'm not getting your point : How $f_n$ converges pointwise to zero function ?

Comment: First of all realize that $f\in L^1(\mu)$ implies $|f(x)|<\infty$ $\mu$-almost everywhere. Now remember that for pointwise convergence we only have to find a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for fixed $x$ and not all $x$. So fix $x_0 \in X$ with $|f(x_0)|<\infty$ and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $N>|f(x_0)|$. Then for all $n\geq N$ $x_0$ is not contained in $X_n$ (by definition of $X_n$). So $\chi_{X_n}(x_0)=0$ and therefore (g_n) converges pointwise $\mu$-almost everywhere to the zero function (sorry I forgot the almost everywhere).